# Unfamiliar C++ syntax while I'm trying to study data structures in C++

Tags: c++

I'm about to learn Data Structures in C++ but I'm suffering from facing to unfamiliar C++ syntax , like :

```
enum SeatStatus SeaList[Max_Seats];
```

all I know about using "enum" in C++ is like :

```
enum direction{up,right,down,left} ; // 0 , 1 , 2 , 3
```

For analyzing an algorithm that is implemented in C++ programming language , I face to a huge amount of unfamiliar codes. Please help me fix this matter out. Thanks to stackoverflow community .

Comment: Get some newer version of the reference materials

Answer (score 7):

It is declaring an array of `enums` of type `SeatStatus`. The array is named `SeaList`. This presupposes `enum SeatStatus` has been defined previously.

This formulation might look more familiar:

```
SeatStatus SeaList[Max_Seats];
```

It is handy in situations where there is something else called `SeatStatus`. For example

```
enum SeatStatus { GOOD, BAD };
const int Max_Seats = 42;

int main()
{
  int SeatStatus;                     // Oh-oh, another SeatStatus!
  SeatStatus SeaList[Max_Seats];      // ERROR: SeatStatus is int object
  enum SeatStatus SeaList[Max_Seats]; // OK, we mean the enum
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me figure out  this matter . please read the text I wrote after the 2nd line of code and share your idea with me about it .

Comment: @ErFun That's a bit broad and off-topic for SO. I would probably try to study data structures either in a language-agnostic way or with a programming language I already know, and study C++ at the same time but separately. Also bear in mind it isn't all about *syntax*. The *semantics* of a language are the main thing. There are many C-like languages out there with very different semantics. The syntactical similarities can actually create a lot of confusion instead of helping.

Comment: Thank you so much . Plus I eliminated the extra texts from my question .

Answer (score 6):

The `enum` in your line is not for defining a new `enum`-type, but a left-over from the languages C-heritage.

It says that `SeatStatus` is an `enum`-type earlier defined, and now we want an array of it.